# Set a variable's value depending on result from the function - MySQL

Tags: mysql, variables, concatenation

I have this query -:
`SET @var = ''; SELECT * FROM dict WHERE checkWord(word) = 'yes'`;

When the result from the checkWord() function is other than 'yes' i.e. when its 'no', i would want concat the value of word which was sent to the function to the existing value of `@var`.

Like for example -: 
 `If checkWord(word) = 'no', then @var = CONCAT(@var,',',word);`

Answer (score 1):

[`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) should do the trick:

```
SELECT group_concat(word) into @var FROM dict WHERE checkWord(word) = 'yes';
```